# google signature verification failed

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, payment

we have problems with our google in app purchase. On some (but only some!!) payments we receive an error when verifying the google Signature in our Java Backend:

Signature length not correct: got 217 but was expecting 256

The incorrect length differs from 217,218,261,262,263

But most of the payments work as expected.

We use the following code to verify in Java:

```
private boolean verifySignature(String signedData, String signature)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
    Signature sig;
    PublicKey publicKey = generatePublicKey();
    if (publicKey == null) {
        return false;
    }
    sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    sig.initVerify(publicKey);
    sig.update(signedData.getBytes());
    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    if (!sig.verify(base64.decode(signature))) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Does anybody know how to get rid of this issue?